# How to send a custom event/signal from on process to another process in MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I have two MacOS applications both are written by QT (c++). The application **B** processes some data and stores the result in a file or shared memory, once finish, the application **A** will use this result and go further.

My question is when **B** finished the data processing, how can it informs **A**? One stupid way is let **A** keeps checking the output file or shared memory. But I actually want more elegant solution, in Windows, I can use system API like SendMessage to post a custom message to **A**, and **A** overrides the QT function **nativeEvent** to handle the message and go further. But I don't know how to do it in MacOS, is there any QT/C++ solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

MacOS is basically UNIX.

Method one: You can send signals, if you have the PID.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_signal_handling.htm

Method two: set up a socket connection. This is probably what I'd do. I'd embed a REST server in program B and have program A send a REST call.